# Excel VBA macro to loop thorugh values and group them

Tags: vba, excel

EDITED TO MAKE IT MORE CLEAR

Let's say I have rows with an account number in column B and non relevant data in column I and then I have rows with non relevant data in column B and a string containing account number and other info in column I. I want to group rows with the same account number and preferably paste them (grouped) to another sheet.

In short, I need to pull up accounts from column B and put them into a "database".  Then I need to loop through the sheet looking for those values in column B and in column I (column I contains more than just the accounts, hence InStr) and group the rows that contain the same account number.

By group I mean to put them in adjacent rows (order is not relevant) and separate different accounts by a blank row. Moving to another spreadsheet is a nice bonus, but not mandatory.

Here's an 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfdrX.png) of a database

Btw same accounts may occur multiple times in both columns and I need to group all of them.

Here's what I have to start, but obviously it does not work.

```
Sub Group_Accounts()

Dim strConcatList As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim K As Long, r As Range
K = 1
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Set w1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set w2 = Sheets("Sheet5")

For Each r In Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If r.Value <> "" Then
        strConcatList = strConcatList & r.Value & "|"
    End If
Next r


For Each r In Intersect(Range("I:I"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

    If InStr(strConcatList, r.Value) > 0 Then
        r.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=w2.Cells(K, 1)
        K = K + 1
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: This could be accomplished easier with a Pivot Table, or Pivot Query.

Comment: A few screenshots of what you need to achieve can help a lot of your question.

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: @ashleedawg - can you please elaborate?

Comment: ...before I elaborate, it would be helpful if you could provide an **Excel** screenshot of your sample data (or, is the image of an non-Excel data source that you need to pull the data from?)  Can you also show an example of what the data should look like _after_ processing?

Comment: the screenshot I added is from Excel. It would be best if the processed data looked like:
- rows with account number "1234567" in column B
- rows with account number "1234567" in column I
- blank row
- rows with account number "7654321" in column B
- rows with account number "7654321" in column I
- blank row, etc.

Comment: also there are multiple account numbers and I need to treat column "B" as the "database" and looping through the database find those account numbers in column "I" and then group them together as described above.